# What is the largest population a single spaceship could sustain?

Tags: space, population

In this setting I'm brainstorming, a significant percentage of humans live not in planets or static habitats, but in massive ships that traverse the cosmos at ultrarelativistic speeds. As such, these ships must have everything required to sustain large permanent populations.

The design I'm thinking off is a series of rotating stanford toruses stacked on top of each other, like a pile of donuts, with the engines/propulsion at the bottom of the pile and the bridge at the top. Some of the toruses would be covered by high-density buildings like skyscrapers, while others would be fully dedicated to agriculture.

Assuming some ten toruses stacked on top of each other, what would be the maximum population these kind of ships could sustain? If that design doesn't work, what alternative designs could provide the highest population in a single ship?

Comment: Lol I'm literally working on the same design, 10 toruses each serving as a habitat ring. The problem is space is MASSIVE, like it can't be understated enough. Interstellar distance is RIDICULOUSLY far, no form of propulsion is realistic, not ion-drive, not nuclear pulse. In all my search the only Pre-Warp technology feasible is Solar-Sails. The main issue is physics; you must push against something to accelerate, if there's nothing to push against you eject mass. Solar Sails technically gets around it by using light. For everything else, there's a maximum point wher acceleration stops.

Comment: The problem is the size of the toruses and the tradeoff between acceleration and total mass.  With the tradeoff on the side of life support, you could theoretically fit the entire human population... if you're willing to take millions of years to get to your destination.

Comment: For interstellar travel I'm thinking of slower-than-light wormholes. For example if the ship is in Sol and opens-up a wormhole to Alpha Centauri for some business and then opens -up another wormhole to come back to Sol, even though for the people in the ship just some weeks or months might have passed, they'll find out it's been 8-10 years for the people back on Earth. These relativistic effects is why a lot of people in the setting decide to just live on spaceships instead of planets/static habitats. So the ship really only needs to be able to move inside systems with "normal" propulsion.

Comment: I misread the original questiona and confused population with propulsion, but I'm not entirely sure what spawned the question? The Stanford Torus is designed to be self-sustainable. The primary exhaustable resource might be H20, everything else they can either grow or harvest from asteroids. H20 would rely on identifying ice from distant asteroids. Vertical farms technology already makes agriculture much easier, scaling up the Torus would provide room for entertainment, I don't think there's obvious population limitations. The restriction comes to resources.

Comment: Given that the Stanford Torus was apparently designed for 10,000 to 140,000 people, it's trivial to multiply by 10.  So it's slightly unclear what you are asking - are you looking for whether there are limits on how far a Stanford Torus can be scaled up? (Hint:  Can only be answered with current material technology knowledge, which has clearly been superseded if these ships are accelerating to relativistic speeds.)  Might be better to pick the population size your story requires and see what the issues are rather than an open-ended question.

Comment: I guess the question would be, is this design the most population efficient, or are there alternate designs which would maximize the population to much higher numbers?

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief "H20 would rely on identifying ice from distant asteroids." Umm... what speed your starship moves relative to those asteroids? Because the "ice harvesting boat" will probably need to decelerate to capture the asteroid intact (as opposed to blow up itself and the asteroid) then accelerate back to catch with the main ship. As a mental exercise, imagine picking up a bottle from the side of a highway while driving a truck at 120km/h.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi In my design the generation ship (stacked toruses) will have a sizable fleet that "scouts ahead" by 6 months~1 year and collect resources. I'm not that far along developing that world but I don't think thats an insurmountable problem? The generationship will have its own on-board mass accelerators to deploy the fleet.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief "I don't think thats an insurmountable problem?" Better check the benefit/cost balance, if you are using water constituents as ejection mass. One wouldn't want to discover that the cost of harvesting the water if greater than the amount of water that can be brought on board from the trip.

Comment: You're not stopping to mine if you're traveling at ultrarelativistic velocity.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief at "ultrarelativistic speeds", it's...pretty bad, even without the rocket equation. Above 0.87c, your kinetic energy exceeds the energy equivalent of your rest mass, and that's not even particularly relativistic, with a Lorentz factor of only 2...it goes up steeply from there. In short, those "boats" will have to convert many times their final mass completely to energy in order to catch back up with the main ship. And applying that kind of energy in an "accelerator" without utterly destroying not only the boat but the atoms it's made of would be a neat trick...

Comment: In short, if you want casual ultrarelativistic travel, you better be able to pull unlimited quantities of energy straight from a neighboring universe or something, because mere antimatter doesn't have enough of a punch. And your drives will be planet-destroying superweapons, never mind what you could do to things by just throwing junk at them.

Comment: How big? The Stanford Torus houses roughly 1,000 people per million tons, although that ratio does improve *slightly* at larger diameters, but the population proposals range from a total population of 10,000 up to 140,000. Without a total mass or a particular version, with a link, this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: My inner snark tells me the OP found the Stanford Torus on google search, thought the picture looked pretty, didn't bother reading about it, and did not realize the Torus is pretty well known and already has clearly defined supported population size. The answer for Torus x10 is quite simply up to 140,000 x10 = 1.4 million absent any other defined parameters/limitations presented by the OP.

Comment: Another issue is the combination of "ultrarelativistic speeds" and centrifugal gravity: the ability to travel at ultrarelativistic speeds implies the ability to simply accelerate at 1 *g* for the entire journey, making centrifugal gravity redundant. A torus would be an awkward and relatively fragile way to arrange the habitats, they would be much easier to shield if arranged as a compact tower with the engines "down".

Comment: @LNSS I reread your post and comments a few times and I think it's a poorly worded question. Since you have been consistent in focusing on population, you should delete the line of "Assume 10 toruses stacked on eachother" because that is the equivalent of asking "Assume I have 10 Honda Civics. How many people can I transport?"

I suggest revise the question to define what is this ship needs to accomplish, what are the expected dilemmas it must overcome, what resources it has access to (are there systems will stop by? If not, why travel at ultrarelativistic speeds?) etc.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/what-would-be-the-size-of-the-biggest-possible-space-ship

This answer may help.

Answer (score 1):

Having separate buildings in an inhabited torus is illogical.  The inhabited torus should be a single vast building, unless you really want the image of separate buildings for some silly reason.

And food should not be grown in single level toruses.  Instead the agricultural toruses should also be occupied by giant single buildings with many floors devoted to growing food using hydroponic or aeroponic methods.  Or more likely the agricultural buildings would be vast machines to synthasize food from waste and other raw materials.